# setting the classpath for a newly injected class

Tags: java, classpath, code-injection

Context:
A new class say Bar, is injected into the JVM at run-time. This class belongs to a package say com.foo.
A reference to this class is injected into another class that belongs to the same package.
The new class may have a different name each time it is loaded - so this cannot be specified as part of any config file - e.g. cannot be specified in build.xml to be included as part of a jar file.

Issue:
At class load time, jvm throws an error - java Result 1. Although I cannot conclusively determine the root cause, it looks like the newly injected class is not being found by class loader.
The server was run in verbose mode which shows the list of classes loaded by the JVM and this newly injected class is seen loaded.

Question:
Is the newly injected class already in the classpath? If not how to set it?

[Edit] - adding some code to the question.

Code segment - 1: This code segment below is called from the PreMain method - Premain method will be called by JVM agent and will inject the instrumentation reference at run time. Premain method injects 1 new class - Bar - and 1 reference to this new class from a method - returnsABool() - in an existing class - ExistingClass.

```
public static void premain(String agentArgs, Instrumentation inst) {

        // 1. Create and load the new class - Bar
        String className = "Bar";
        byte [] b = getBytesForNewClass();
        //override classDefine (as it is protected) and define the class.
        Class clazz = null;
        try {
          ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
          Class cls = Class.forName("java.lang.ClassLoader");
          java.lang.reflect.Method method =
            cls.getDeclaredMethod("defineClass", new Class[] { String.class, byte[].class, int.class, int.class });
          // protected method invocation
          method.setAccessible(true);
          try {
            Object[] args = new Object[] { className, b, new Integer(0), new Integer(b.length)};
            clazz = (Class) method.invoke(loader, args);
          } finally {
            method.setAccessible(false);
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
         System.err.println(
            "AllocationInstrumenter was unable to create new class" + e.getMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // 2. Inject some lines of code into the returnsABool method in ExistingClass class that references Bar
        inst.addTransformer(new CustomInstrumenter(), true);

        // end of premain method
}
```

Code sement 2: The method returnsABool() needs to be byte-injected with the commented 
lines shown below. The code to byte inject this is also called from the PreMain method.

```
public class ExistingClass{

    public static boolean returnsABool() {
     // Code within comments is byte-injected, again as part of the pre-main method

     /*
     String str = Bar.get();
     if (str != "someValue") {
      return true;
     }
     */

        return false;
    }
}
```

Byte code injection for ExistingClass - done using asm library

```
{  
    MethodVisitor mv = cv.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);  
    mv.visitCode();  
    Label l0 = new Label();  
    mv.visitLabel(l0);   
    mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "com/Bar", "get", "()Ljava/lang/String;");        
    mv.visitLdcInsn("some constant here");   
    Label l1 = new Label();   
    mv.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.IF_ACMPNE, l1);   
    mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ICONST_0); Label l2 = new Label();   
    mv.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.GOTO, l2);   
    mv.visitLabel(l1);   
    mv.visitFrame(Opcodes.F_SAME, 0, null, 0, null);   
    mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ICONST_1); 
    mv.visitFrame(Opcodes.F_SAME1, 0, null, 1, new Object[] {Opcodes.INTEGER});  
    mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.IRETURN);   
    mv.visitMaxs(2, 0);   
    mv.visitEnd();   
}
```

Comment: How, specifically, is the class being "injected"? Is it dynamically created and loaded by the classloader?

Comment: Some java code would be useful, otherwise it is very difficult to help you. Also, maybe this question is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4210346/74694

Comment: Show a minimal example demonstrating the problem you have.

Comment: Bert, yes this dynamic class is created and loaded by the classoader.

Comment: @Neeme, @Thorjam, I have included Java code snippets

Comment: @crazy horse: your code is not properly formatted, please use the 01010101 button. And, it would be helpful, if you would state what this code aims to achieve.

Comment: I tried out your system-classloader injection code and at least under normal circumstances (simple "main" method), it seems to work all right (I used javac-generated bytecode). So I would suspect your bytecode generation logic. Or how do you inject the code to the ExistingClass?

Comment: Also, "jvm throws an error - java Result 1" is not very informative. Maybe you can add more details about the resulting error?

Comment: @Neeme, Thank you. Unfortunately I dont see any detailed error message. When I run the ANT script, all I see is a Java result 1.

Comment: @Neeme, Added the byte-injection for the ExistingClass

Comment: @Neeme, Added the byte-injection for the ExistingClass

Comment: Could the "Java result 1." be demystified using the technique here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230940/how-to-resolve-java-result-1-errors

Comment: I would suggest you to get rid of agent for now and run the same code from regular "main" method. Maybe that will have better error handling?

Comment: @Neeme, @Martin, yes agree - I will get rid of the agent for now and try it out in a main method. I am out of town now and will try this when I am back. Appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suspect you have something wrong with your bytecode generation, the following ASM code works for me:

```
        mv.visitCode();
        Label l0 = new Label();
        mv.visitLabel(l0);
        mv.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, "com/Bar", "get", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
        Label l1 = new Label();
        mv.visitLdcInsn("some constant here");
        mv.visitJumpInsn(Opcodes.IF_ACMPEQ, l1);
        mv.visitFrame(Opcodes.F_SAME, 0, null, 0, null);
        mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ICONST_1);
        mv.visitFrame(Opcodes.F_SAME, 0, null, 1, new Object[] {Opcodes.INTEGER});
        mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.IRETURN);
        mv.visitLabel(l1);
        mv.visitFrame(Opcodes.F_SAME, 0, null, 0, null);
        mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.ICONST_0);
        mv.visitFrame(Opcodes.F_SAME, 0, null, 1, new Object[] {Opcodes.INTEGER});
        mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.IRETURN);
        mv.visitMaxs(2, 1);
        mv.visitEnd();
```

Also note that:

- the way you are comparing Strings will most likely lead to issues, you should use `str.equals(str2)`
- **you are replacing the entire method**, instead of injecting your custom code in the beginning (your comments seem to indicate that you want to inject, instead of replace)

Comment: Fantastic - Thank You Neeme - this (use of equals) solved the issue - lesson learnt the hard way!

Comment: Just to complete the answer, it looks like classes injected at run-time are already in the class-path.

Comment: @crazy horse: I used ASM Eclipse plugin (http://asm.ow2.org/eclipse/index.html) and hand-tuned the generated code a bit to make it look more similar to yours.